# Overlapping lines with OpenGl

Tags: opengl, line, opacity, opengl-compat

I have two lines that cross each other and I have set the opacity for these lines to `0.7`. Here's the code:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glLineWidth(7);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor4f(0.9, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0.8f);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.8f);
glEnd();
glLineWidth(10);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor4f(0.9, 0.3, 0.4,0.7);
glVertex2f(-0.89f, -1.0f);
glVertex2f(-0.89f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
```

Here is the output of this: [image: code output]

Since the lines opacities are set to `0.7` the part where the lines intersect should have been a little darker than the rest of the line. How can I get that kind of effect?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You're using pre multiplied alpha in your blender. Use GL_ONE for the second parameter to glBlendFunc

Comment: no, it just made the colors brighter

Comment: Yes it works now thank you

Comment: @Jhon Was it the depth test or the alpha channel?

Comment: The depth test, i disabled it

Answer (score 0):

So it was the depth test, makes sense. It just overwrote the same spot in the zbuffer. But the note about the premultiplied alpha still counts. Using the blender you specified originally you would have to multiply the rgb values by the alpha to get the color you wanted.